# How render view with programmatically passed parameters of contextual filter

Tags: 8, hooks

I am using Drupal 8. Added new view My Vocabulary and created a contextual filter with paragraph ID. Now I need to render the view with passed parameters to contextual filter. What hook to use to solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: can you explain what do you want to achieve exactly ? where do you want to render this view and so on ?

Comment: I created My Vocabulary page. This page must be loaded with a contextual filter. This contextual filter takes IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [hook_views_pre_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_view/8.2.x)

```
function mymodule_views_pre_view(\Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view, $display_id, array &$args) {
  // Modify contextual filters for view_name.
  $paragraph_id = 22;
  if ($view->id() == 'view_name') {
    $args = [$paragraph_id]; // args must be an array.
  }
}
```